# Angular how to get the URL of a bad link

Tags: angular

In my application I have a component that matches the router's wildcard to catch ad links like this:

```
const route: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
       (etc)
  { path: '**', component: BadlinkComponent }
];
```

In the **BadlinkComponent** I import the **AcivatedRoute** object:

```
export class BadlinkComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

But I can't find the property or method that gives me the bad route.  Can someone point out what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `snapshot` to catch the url

```
export class BadlinkComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(router.snapshot['_routerState'].url); 
 }
}
```

Comment: The snapshot property is easy to miss and misunderstand when you don't use it regularly.

Comment: `_routerState` is meant for internal use so it's better to use the public api

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `url` method of `ActivatedRoute`

```
const url: Observable<string> = route.url.map(segments => segments.join(''));
```